# Resizing the image stored outside root directory

Tags: php

I m storing all images in a folder outside root directory for security purpose. But I cannot get to resize the image when displaying it on a webpage. Image appears in its full size.
How to resize the image for displaying in webpage.

```
<?php
// The path where the images are stored.
$imgLocation = '/Applications/XAMPP/im/';


$imgName = 'tesla.jpg';

// Construct the actual image path.
$imgPath = $imgLocation . $imgName;

// Make sure the file exists
if(!file_exists($imgPath) || !is_file($imgPath)) {
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
die('The file does not exist');
}

// Make sure the file is an image
$imgData = getimagesize($imgPath);
if(!$imgData) {
header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
die('The file you requested is not an image.');
}

// Set the appropriate content-type
// and provide the content-length.
header('Content-type: ' . $imgData['mime']);
header('Content-length: ' . filesize($imgPath));

// Print the image data
readfile($imgPath);

?>
```

Comment: no.. i haven't. Cant it be done using backend only.

Comment: i dont wanna put images in root...thats y asking this question here.

Comment: For the purpose of displaying the images on a website, its better to create the URL for the image and not use the directory path (which may not even work). You can then use height/width options of html img tag to resize your image for display purposes.